# audioplayer playing inconsistent / weird audio (url mp3 link) result in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, audio, https, audio-player

following the instructions from:
https://codingwithjoe.com/playing-audio-from-the-web-and-http/ (using his example and AudioProvider class)

I have been using:

```
  audioplayer: ^0.8.1
  audioplayer_web: ^0.7.1
```

to play audio from https link.

The problem it has some weird inconsistent effect.
- after playing few audio, it keeps on playing the same audio eventhough new url is loaded
- after playing few audio, the sound is weird like some part is cut with other audio.

What is a good audio player that accepts url link for flutter that can produce a consistent result ?

Comment: the provided audioplayer from your example works great and has good features. From what you are describing for me it seems like you're not closing the session when you play a sound. It seems like you are stacking the sounds which causes weird sounds. You have to close the instance then.

Comment: possibly. how do I close the instance. I tried to maybe use audioProvider = null before AudioProvider audioProvider = new AudioProvider(url);

Comment: for the example, it looks like its using the same audio.mp3 file on local.

Comment: check my answer. on the provided links u can find updated examples. Also i linked you an alternative player if you cant make the updated version work. hope it helps. @Axil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the provided audioplayer from your example works great and has good features. From what you are describing for me it seems like you're not closing the session when you play a sound. It seems like you are stacking the sounds which causes weird sounds.

You have to close the instance then. even though the article is outdated (march 2018) the audioplayer has developed further. check their offical guide here:

https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayer

This is version `audioplayer 0.8.1` not 3.0 or something..

Example from docs:

```
Instantiate an AudioPlayer instance
//...
AudioPlayer audioPlugin = AudioPlayer();
//...
```

Player controls:

```
audioPlayer.play(url);

audioPlayer.pause();

audioPlayer.stop();
```

status and current position:

```
//...
_positionSubscription = audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen(
  (p) => setState(() => position = p)
);

_audioPlayerStateSubscription = audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((s) {
  if (s == AudioPlayerState.PLAYING) {
    setState(() => duration = audioPlayer.duration);
  } else if (s == AudioPlayerState.STOPPED) {
    onComplete();
    setState(() {
      position = duration;
    });
  }
}, onError: (msg) {
  setState(() {
    playerState = PlayerState.stopped;
    duration = new Duration(seconds: 0);
    position = new Duration(seconds: 0);
  });
});
```

Like I said most of the audio plugins are running in singleton mode with instances. To provide getting weird effects you have to load the next song in the same instance, don't open another new instance, and you wont get any weird effects.

If you want to switch to a different audio player another great one which I used in an app project is the following:

https://pub.dev/packages/audio_manager#-readme-tab-

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot, will try to review. i open in audioplayer in several pages to play different audio.not sure if i should open once the instance and manage it or close the instance after play. I prefer the later one but have to see how to close the instance ? is it just setting to null closes the instance ?

Comment: im not sure how it works with the audioplayer plugin, but in the other one I provided you as alternative, you have one player instance and you will give it a list of songs where you can decide to play them later on. Im managing the instance with Providers to make it work on multiple pages. would be nice if you can mark the answer as useful so other people can check it faster too.

Comment: the answer was quite simple. audioPlayer.play(url); All I need was to put the url in there and there is no need to use AudioProvider for decoding the url and store in local.